# C++ Convert from packed DATE to CTime

Tags: c++, time

I have looked but cannot find the API to convert from DATE to CTime and vice versa.  Is there such a thing?

Comment: It would help if you told us what "packed DATE" format you had in mind (and probably the same for `CTime`, especially if you're *not* talking about the MFC thing).

Comment: I am talking about MFC CTime and DATE (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82ab7w69(vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a shorter method, but going by the docs you can store a DATE in a COleDateTime, get that as a SYSTEMTIME and then use that to construct your CTime. Assuming it's representable as a CTime.

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
DATE d(whatever);
COleDateTime ole(d);
d.GetAsSystemTime(st);
CTime ct(st);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Will try doing the reverse as I actually need to convert from CTime to DATE.

Answer (score 0):

CTime include a number of constructors and converters for various time formats; it seems odd that `DATE` is not included. However `_time64_t` is supported, and differs from `DATE` only in the starting date and scale. You can easily convert from one to another if you have the starting date of January 1, 1970 as a `DATE` value:

```
DATE       jan1_1970 = ????;
__time64_t t;
DATE       d;
double     seconds_per_day = 24.*60.*60.;
t = (d - jan1_1970) * seconds_per_day;
d = (t / seconds_per_day) + jan1_1970;
```